# Grails how to rerender

Tags: java, grails, groovy, gsp

I have lots of json files like

```
{ 
  "first": A, 
  "second" : [B,C,D]
}.
```

I have a contoller and a view.

```
 def index() { 
    render(view: "index", model: [A: json.A, B: json.arr])
 }
```

.gsp

```
<h2> ${A}</h2>       
    <g:each var="b" in="${B}" status="counter">
      <h2>${b}</h2>
 </g:each>
```

In controller I need to read a current json file, then render a page with these json data. Then in view I want to press button next, which will send some data to controller and render the same page with another data.

Button next sends data through .ajax .
All data are properly collected, the first page renders without problems. The problem is that new data doesnt shown in the page until I call

```
location.reload();
```

in console.

Is there any way to make my page reload in controller?

Comment: You can get every new data in ajax response, no need to reload the page.

Comment: after ajax success of new data, call one fuction which will construct your DOM dynamically, currently you are constructing DOM  using gsp model data so, you need to reload page every time

Comment: @NitinDhomse, OK, thanks I'll try it.